# finding variation between two images

Tags: c++

[image: left side is "normal"; right side is to be detected]

I have a program (C++/CImg) that loops through video stills and returns an image like either of the pictures above, as well as the dark pixel locations. There's only one x-value per y-value, so fitting an equation would be trivial. At some point, the images change from the nice parabolic shape seen on the left and inverts one or both sides, as seen on the right. This is probably more of a mathematical question than a pure coding question, but is there any marker that clearly differentiates between the two types of image? I can't just match pixel to pixel because intermediate images will have slight variations.

I'm not looking for code help yet; I just need ideas to get the ball rolling.

Comment: Can you check for left and right slopes? If you are looking for sharp corners, then `dx/dy|+` (slope of x as a function of y when approached from larger y values) is going to be significantly different from `dx/dy|-` (slope of x as a function of y when approached from smaller y values) at the sharp corner.

Comment: To look at the second derivative might help. You seem to be looking for the points of inflection.